# Compose inspection unavailable. Could not determine the version of the androidx.compose.ui:ui artifact. Try a different version of compose

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose, layout-inspector

I'm getting the error message above when trying to use Layout inspector on my Project when I'm using Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Canary 6.

I also tried it with Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1. There I only get the error message: Compose inspection is not available.

For version Control I'm using chris banes's BOM

```
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.0'
    }

dependencies{
androidx.compose = 2023.02.00-alpha02
..
implementation platform("dev.chrisbanes.compose:compose-bom:${androidx.compose}")
    androidTestImplementation platform("dev.chrisbanes.compose:compose-bom:${androidx.compose}")
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-util"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview"
```

I also tried to use own verrsions without using the BOM but that gave me the same issue.
Invalidating Cache and Rebuilding Project also didn't work.

Has anybody an idea how I can fix this and start using my Layout inspector again?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? none of the answers seem to work

Comment: Same here.. issue persist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Fix

As mentioned previously, the fix is to bump compose-ui to `1.4.0-beta02`:

```kotlin
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.4.0-beta02")
```

(or via [Version Catalogs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html):)

```ini
name-of-library = "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.4.0-beta02"
# Or
name-of-library = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui", version = "1.4.0-beta02" }
```

Or to use [2023.02.00-beta03](https://github.com/chrisbanes/compose-bom/releases/tag/v2023.02.00-beta03) of the [alpha Compose BoM](https://github.com/chrisbanes/compose-bom):

```kotlin
implementation(platform("dev.chrisbanes.compose:compose-bom:2023.02.00-beta03"))
```

(or via [Version Catalogs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html):)

```ini
name-of-bom = "dev.chrisbanes.compose:compose-bom:2023.02.00-beta03"
# Or
name-of-bom = { module = "dev.chrisbanes.compose:compose-bom", version = "2023.02.00-beta03" }
```

### Rationale

This is because the `androidx.compose.ui_ui.version` file (in the `META-INF` directory of a built APK) that the [Layout Inspector expects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/studio#layout-inspector) has an invalid version:

```
task ':compose:ui:ui:writeVersionFile' property 'version'
```

(Curiously enough, this also happens for some other dependency versions:)

(`androidx.browser_browser.version`)

```
task ':browser:browser:writeVersionFile' property 'version'
```

Some quick googling in [Google's IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) led to [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/267734369), which documents the bug affecting versions `1.4.0-alpha05`, `1.4.0-alpha06` and `1.4.0-beta01`.

A [fix was then submitted](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2433397) to resolve the version issue, and has since been applied to `1.4.0-beta02` [(released on 22 Feb)](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.4.0-beta02).

#### Additional info

This bug appears to have been caused by a [prior change to convert the properties in the `VersionFileWriterTask` file](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/a0f68c668bf2e88b6ed5b46fc18a31473dcfda57) (used to write the version file) to use [Gradle's lazily configured properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#lazy_properties):

```kotlin
@get:Input
lateinit var version: String // Before
abstract val version: Property<String> // After (note the use of Property)
```

However, as `version` is now wrapped around Gradle's [`Property`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/Property.html) interface, it will then require additional code to retrieve its value, in this case with a simple [`get()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/Provider.html#get--) call ([as shown in the most recent commit](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/164bf7022221604131e539673cdf09cdb46f53da)):

```kotlin
writer.println(version) // Before
writer.println(version.get()) // After
```

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to @Edric's response I found the issue why layout inspector won't work for me.

I had the below code in my `gradle.kts` file

```kotlin
packagingOptions {
    resources.excludes.add("META-INF/**")
}
```

You will need to remove it and add to the root of the gradle file

```kotlin
androidComponents {
    onVariants(selector().withBuildType("release")) {
        it.packaging.resources.excludes.add("META-INF/**")
    }
}
```

EG:

```kotlin
android {
   ...
}

androidComponents {
    onVariants(selector().withBuildType("release")) {
        it.packaging.resources.excludes.add("META-INF/**")
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried moving it to root but same issue

Comment: Can you generate an APK and inspect if `META-INF` folder exist in the apk. Thats need for layout inspector to work.

Comment: Yes it does exist

Comment: Works fine in March 2024

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try updating to the latest version to see if that helps:

```
api(platform("dev.chrisbanes.compose:compose-bom:2023.02.00-beta02"))
```

The current `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` is `1.4.2`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I still get the same message as before and inspecting doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the line implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui" to implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.4.0-beta02' and it works

Comment: Thanks for the help. In the end it was both your answer and CodePoet that showed me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [CodePoet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5513788/code-poet) and [VangelNum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19706999/vangelnum) both of them helped me significantly.

After some trying out with the versions they suggested I found out the following:

I need to use

```
androidx.compose = '2023.02.00-beta02'
```

And change the version of ui:ui to

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.4.0-beta02'
//keep in mind: "" is not the same as ''
```

Here you need to be careful as I tried several times with "..." and it didn't work. You need to use '...' that it takes the written version.

Like this it works for me.

Update: just using

```
androidx.compose = '2023.02.00-beta03'
```

Also does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reported bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/246355403

In my case, I had this block

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += "META-INF/*.version"
        }
    }
}
```

Remove `excludes += "META-INF/*.version"` did the trick

Comment: Doesn't work, at least not anymore. It will show the warning saying 
"Could not determine the version of the androidx.compose.ui:ui artifact. Was the version file excluded?"

Answer (score 0):

Changing compose UI version from 1.6.0-alpha08 to 1.5.4 fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

go to your sdk tools and install layout inspector for different apis